# Extraer un cadena de texto de un HTML en R

Tags: html, r, rstudio

Estoy trabajando en R Studio y tengo un html, he conseguido crear una tabla con el contenido que necesito, pero resulta que el programa que me crea el archivo .htm es Metatrader 4 y las variables las añade como titulo de la fila como puedes ver más abajo.
Por lo que estoy intentando extraer el texto y convertirlo después en campos dentro de la columna ya que son variables.

el texto es:

```
<td title="SL=1900; DistMaxima=700; Horas=4; 
Margen=180;Operaciones=1;
Volumen=0.01; ">21</td>
```

el "21" es el campo referencia y sí, me lo está añadiendo correctamente ya que esta fuera de

```
<td> </td>
```

y me gustaría convertirlo en columnas

SL |   DistMaxima | Horas | Margen| Operaciones | Volumen |

Esta misma cadena en el archivo se repite más de 1000 veces por lo que creo que debería de ser mediante una función, pero no encuentro la libreria o la forma correcta.

Una forma de encontrarla creo que sería que mediante alguna función que buscara

```
<td title=" ****************** ">
```

ya que siempre cumple esta norma y lo fuera añadiendo a un data frame para trabajarlo después, pero tampoco se como hacerlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

el código que he usado es:

```
#Cargamos las librerias necesarias 
library(XML)

#Añadimos la url de la Optimización
Optimizador_url <- "../Data/AUDJPY-PV-104-1H.htm" 

#Guardamos las tablas en data.frame
Tablas <- readHTMLTable(Optimizador_url)

#seleccionamos y guardamos la tabla que nos interesa
operaciones <- Tablas[[2]]

str(operaciones) 
head(operaciones)
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? ¿Podrías publicar el código con lo que tengas? La idea es que todas las preguntas tengan un [mcve]. El botón para **[edit]** está si pie de tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias @Mariano ya he añadido lo poco que tengo, disculpa no haberlo hecho bien de primeras ;)

Comment: ¿Hola podrías compartir el archivo html?, se me ocurre que puedes usar el paquete rvest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría funcionar.

```
web<-'<td title="SL=1900; DistMaxima=700; Horas=4; 
Margen=180;Operaciones=1;
Volumen=0.01; ">21</td>
<td title="SL=1900; DistMaxima=800; Horas=4; 
Margen=180;Operaciones=1;
Volumen=0.01; ">23</td>'
```

leer los datos y cargar librerías

```
web<-read_html(web)    
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
```

se obtiene un vector de todos los atributos `title` de las etiquetas `td`

```
data<-web%>%html_nodes("td")%>%html_attrs()
data<-unlist(data)
data<-data[names(data)=="title"]
```

se extraen los datos numéricos

```
data<-data%>%str_extract_all("[0-9]+\\.*\\d*")
```

se guaran en un data.frame

```
data<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, data)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rolando Tamayo, se han extraido los valores correctamente, ahora los fusionré con la tabla de los resultados!